# gvim Windows - Message popup box with OK button?

Tags: vim

I am running  gvim version 7.4 on Windows.  Everytime i start gvim, before it loads the window with multiple tabs that i have,  i get a popup.  First thing i would see is this popup titled  "Message"  and  it contains the following  lines,  with an  "OK"  button at bottom.  If i click the ok button, gvim starts running without any further problems. I have not been able to find anything in google searches.  What is the cause of this popup, and how to eliminate it ?

---

```
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py"   
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py" [unix] 332L, 
10531C

"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\using_update.30ad2dc2bda6.py"   
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\using_update.30ad2dc2bda6.py" [unix] 
110L, 2680C

"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blogPostDAO.py"    
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blogPostDAO.py" [unix] 
144L, 4261C

"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blogPostDAO.py.b4vim.orig"
```

---

**Additions after couple of replies:::**

Thanks for the replies, Ingo Karkat and romain. I took a look into the vimlog file. It is 26000 lines long. So i searched for the first filename  *blog.py* which occurs only in the following section of **vimlog** output file.  The corresponding region of *vimsession* file is also given below.

```
line 140: badd +113 Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py  
line 141: badd +0 Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blogPostDAO.py.b4vim.orig  
line 142: silent! argdel *   
Error detected while processing C:\nirmal\vimsession:   
line  142:   
E480: No match: *   
line 143: set lines=43 columns=171  
line 144: edit Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py  
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py"   
"Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py" [unix] 332L, 10531C
```

Since the above output contained an error at line 142, i took a look at my  *vimsession*  file. BTW, i have  the very last statement of  my  *_vimrc*  file as *source vimsession*.  Even if i delete my vimsession file (while i have my gvim session open), and recreate it from the open gvim session, i still get the same kind of message box. I took a look at the help pages for  *argdel*  which occurs in line 142, causing the error, but unable to figure why this line gets into the vimsession.  Following is the relevant section of my  *vimsession* file,  which pertains to the very first line that comes up in the popup *Message*  window.

```
badd +1 Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py  
badd +98 Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blogPostDAO.py.b4vim.orig  
badd +3466 \Documents\ and\ Settings\bharathil\vimlog  
badd +89 \nsam\vimsession  
silent! argdel *  
set lines=43 columns=171  
edit Week-3-SCHEMA-DESIGN\hw3-2and3-3\blog.py
```

In my readings, I have not yet finished the User Manual, even half way. My  *_vimrc* file is the one that was suggested as starting setup (by the User Manual).  I have only added minimal stuff to it. I don't  understand how the **argdel** gets into the vimsession, since i don't  remember messing with that command at all.  I suspect once i figure out how to fix the error near  *blog.py* (first file in error list),  i will be able to repeat the process, for all the 10 tabs (2 windows in each) and stop this message box from popping up.

Comment: How do you load those "multiple tabs"? Do you use sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is output from stuff in your `~/.vimrc` or plugins that runs *before GVIM is fully initialized*. The execution of those commands should be delayed via

```
:autocmd VimEnter * {commands-here}
```

How to find these commands? You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

Comment: My response is too long to fit in comment. I will add details by editing my original question.

Comment: Sessions can sometimes cause errors, and often messages. Based on your edits, change the last line in your `.vimrc` to `autocmd VimEnter * source vimsession`

Comment: Thank you Ingo, I am glad this fixed my popup problem. Now i have a side effect .....my Buffer list is getting wiped out every time i restart. It is not a bother for me, but i had about 50 files on my buffer list, and they are all gone. But, for future use, i would like to be able to hang onto the future edited files in buffer list, between sessions (this functionality working before). I did try `:mksession! vimsession` just before quitting gvim.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it. If you don't find a solution to your buffer deletion yourself, please submit a separate question for it; it's hard to answer such in a comment.

Comment: I have upvoted and marked this question as answered. 
Obviously i am missing some etiquette of posting questions in stackoverflow, because today i noticed that someone has "down-voted"  this question. I am at a loss to understand why this is down voted. Is it because of the length of the question ? (the only choice i had was to update the question with details, which increased the length).  Since you seem to be a senior member of this website, maybe you direct me, so that i won't repeat mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! While your question certainly could benefit from editing, it reflects the process of arriving at an answer. Don't let a downvote discourage you from participating here!